# Google Analytics API - Number of recent failed reporting API requests is too high

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Sometimes, when I try to run a report using GA api, it returns the following error: "Number of recent failed reporting API requests is too high, please implement exponential back off. "

The error message is referent to the quota limit, but when I check it in the Google Cloud API Console looks like i'm not even close to reach the limits.

The exponential backoff is already implemented and looks like it's working fine, but we still facing the issue eventually, without success to identify it roots or causes.

We are using version 4 of the api in Java.

Here more information about the error:

```
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Quota Error: Number of recent failed reporting API requests is too high, please implement exponential back off.\nSee developer documentation for details at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#reporting_apis_request_errors",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Quota Error: Number of recent failed reporting API requests is too high, please implement exponential back off.\nSee developer documentation for details at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#reporting_apis_request_errors",
  "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}
```

Comment: Hi Rafael,
We get the exact same behavior, even after several interventions at Google (requiring support), although with a different library: PHP.
We're always nowhere near the quotas, and still receinvg at random days this error message.. i've just grown to hate it.!